# How can I use php-curl to post JSON and a file in multipart/form-data?

Tags: php, multipartform-data, php-curl

I have tried multiple ways of doing this and am having no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.  I can successfully import the file through postman but the php curl script it generates does not work.  These are the instructions from the website:

API imports are sent as form-data type requests, with the request body containing following fields:
importRequest: a text field that contains the request JSON.
files: a file field that contains the import file. For the request header, add a Content-Type header with a value of multipart/form-data.

Here is my current code, generated from postman.

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $apiurl,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('importRequest'=>$myJSON,'files'=> new CURLFILE('/C:/Documents/j00119.csv')),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization: Bearer' . $myBearerToken
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Looks ok to me, when you say it doesn't work, can you include the error message you are getting back?

Comment: @bumperbox all I get is a false return.  I tried running verbose mode and get the following which I don't understand since this is postman snippet code and it works when I issue the command directly from postman.  ```*   Trying 104.17.202.204...
* Connected to api.hubapi.com (104.17.202.204) port 443 (#0)
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* NPN, negotiated HTTP1.1
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0```
bool(false)

Comment: https://blog.petehouston.com/fix-ssl-certificate-problem-with-php-curl/

Comment: Thanks for that.  I though I had tried that at one point but must have had the value wrong.  Now that I am past that I get this error ```string(250) "<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 400 Bad Request</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 400</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /crm/v3/imports. Reason:
<pre>    Bad Request</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
"```

Comment: bad request is coming from the server you are calling, check the url, and post values are all as expected. Otherwise if there are public api docs, then maybe post a link to those docs so we can compare what your script is doing to what they are expecting

Comment: Try and leave out the `Content-Type` header. cURL will set that to multipart itself when an array gets passed for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, if you set it yourself, I am not sure if cURL adds the necessary _boundary_ value itself.